# Postgres Gem PG Install with Remote Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems

I just installed a fresh copy of Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3 on a Debian Squeeze server. The Rails web application will need to connect to a remote Postgres database so I tried to install the Postgres adapter but it appears that the installer is looking for a local PostgreSQL database and and configs that aren't there because the Postgres database lives on a different host.

Can someone explain how to install the Postgres adapter when the actual Postgres database lives on a different machine?

Thanks

```
gem1.9.1 install pg


Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again   with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config


checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing libraries on your environment. Try to install all of them before you try to install the `pg` gem.
Alternatively, if the libs are all installed and you are still getting the same error, try installing the gem specifying the postgres config file with the `--with-pg-config` command your error is showing above.

```
gem install pg --with-pg-config=TYPE_HERE_YOUR_postgresql.conf_PATH
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. apt-get install libpq-dev The other config messages were really leading me down the wrong path.

Comment: This answers is not useful. What is TYPE_HERE_YOUR_postgresql.conf_PATH means? is it a jdbc url to postgres???

Comment: It means substitute the text to the path to your postgresql.conf location.